# Validate data from form to controller in laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, ajaxform

Can anyone tell me when i used ajax to send data from form to laravel controller it is best used js to validate data or used laravel controller to validate data or used the two together

Comment: Never trust front-end validation, NEVER.

Comment: I agree with you it best for security resoans to validate data in controller because users can't access on it but to make the steps more logics it prefer to used js validate in frontend and laravel validate in controller

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use the same twice in frontend, used js validate to make form more logics and in backend used laravel validate data because user can't access on it but he can access on frontend